# Three conditions in while statement in java

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-logic

is this wrong? I want to exit the while loop when the Ran1,Ran2,Ran3 are all the same. tnx

```
Random RandomNumber = new Random();
int Ran1 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);
int Ran2 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);
int Ran3 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);

while (Ran1 != Ran2 && Ran1 != Ran3 && Ran2 != Ran3 ){
    Ran1 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);
    Ran2 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);
    Ran3 = RandomNumber.nextInt(4);
    System.out.print(Ran1);
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(Ran2);
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(Ran3);
```

}

Comment: change it to : **while(Ran1 != Ran2 || Ran1 != Ran3 || Ran2 != Ran3)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just simple boolean logic. You can try it yourself. Let's say `Ran1` is 3, `Ran2` is 4, and `Ran3` is 3. What would the expression evaluate to?

```
Ran1 != Ran2 -> 3 != 4 -> True
Ran1 != Ran3 -> 3 != 3 -> False
Ran2 != Ran3 -> 4 != 3 -> True
```

Those are not all True, so `AND`ing them together is False, and your loop would break. But that's not what you want, you want it to only be False when they are all the same. If you notice, the way you have it now, the loop breaks if any one of the three variables equals any other one.

It's easier to think in terms of positives instead of double negatives. When are all the variables the same? It's when `Ran1 == Ran2`, `Ran1 == Ran3`, and `Ran2 == Ran3`, or, in Java syntax:

```
Ran1 == Ran2 && Ran1 == Ran3 && Ran2 == Ran3
```

Now, as long as this is **not** true, you want your loop to continue, so make sure to wrap it in parenthesis and use the `NOT` operator `!`:

```
while (!(Ran1 == Ran2 && Ran1 == Ran3 && Ran2 == Ran3)) {
    ...
}
```

---

That's it, but if you don't want to use parentheses then you can simply the expression using boolean logic. `!(A && B)` is the same as `!A || !B`:

```
A  |  B  |  A && B  |  ! (A && B)  | !A  |  !B  |  !A || !B
---+-----+----------+--------------+-----+------+-----------
T  |  T  |    T     |       F      |  F  |   F  |     F
T  |  F  |    F     |       T      |  F  |   T  |     T
F  |  T  |    F     |       T      |  T  |   F  |     T
F  |  F  |    F     |       T      |  T  |   T  |     T
```

You can verify for yourself that `!(A && B && C)` is the same as `!A || !B || !C`. Thus you can turn the above `while` loop into:

```
while (!(Ran1 == Ran2) || !(Ran1 == Ran3) || !(Ran2 == Ran3)) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
while (Ran1 != Ran2 || Ran1 != Ran3 || Ran2 != Ran3) {
    ...
}
```

In terms of reasoning about it with words: you want the loop to continue so long as ***any*** pair of the three variables aren't equal. Your initial expression `Ran1 != Ran2 && Ran1 != Ran3 && Ran2 != Ran3` would only continue the loop so long as ***all*** pairs of the three variables aren't equal.

Comment: Thx a lot. Im newbie in programing, and your's are very very clear. hehe Tnx again.

Answer (score 4):

You want to exit the loop when they are all the same. Since equality is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), you know that if `A == B && B == C` then `A == C`. This means that you can exit just when

```
Ran1 == Ran2 && Ran1 == Ran3
```

so you must keep inside the loop until the negation of the previous condition is true:

```
! (Ran1 == Ran2 && Ran1 == Ran3)
```

which is equivalent, by using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), to:

```
Ran1 != Ran2 || Ran1 != Ran3
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically yours is fine, but it can be a little shorter/easier to read. You want to use a NOT operator ( `!` ) in the condition, because that's how you think of it:

```
while ( !  ( ( Ran1 == Ran2) && (Ran1 == Ran3) ) )
```

Comment: He wants to exit the loop when they **are all the same**.

Comment: tnx alot. its now working. but still i dont get it. the '&&' = 'and' and '||' = 'or' right?

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep iterating while the 3 values are different each other, so the way to express the condition is

```
while(Ran1 != Ran2 || Ran2 != Ran3 )
```

Because implicitly it means that Ran1 and Ran3 are  equal once you have compared Ran2 with the other ones

BTW, you can simplify your

```
System.out.print(Ran1);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(Ran2);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.println(Ran3);
```

By using a single:

```
System.out.println(Ran1 + " " Ran2 + " " + Ran3);
```